# Stripping Values between two brackets {}

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Afternoon,

I'm trying to query a column that gets data between two brackets. there may be multiple sets in the column such as : {Abrasision} {None} {Bruise}

i use this and it doesn't do exactly what i want, because i think i only use one bracket in the query. i want to get each value in my result set and insert into a table variable. Just having a little bit of trouble.

```
SELECT 
   LEFT(InjuryCategory, CHARINDEX('{', InjuryCategory)-1), 
   SUBSTRING(InjuryCategory, CHARINDEX('{', InjuryCategory)+1, LEN(InjuryCategory)-CHARINDEX('{', InjuryCategory)-CHARINDEX('{',REVERSE(InjuryCategory ))),
   RIGHT(InjuryCategory, CHARINDEX('{', REVERSE(InjuryCategory))-1)  
FROM TblVictim
```

Comment: The problem started with the decision to store *multiple* data values in a type not *designed* for holding multiple values - the string. If you use appropriate data types, this sort of problem is a lot easier. Types designed for holding multiple values available in SQL Server include XML, JSON and *tables*. In a purely SQL solution, those three values should be stored in three *rows* of a table (along with whatever data is required to associate them together)

Comment: Thank you, and I understand the design issue. This is source data. I'm trying to clean it up and move everything into a separate table, one at a time.

Comment: Most likely you should actually have 2 tables; a `Victim` table and an `Injury` table which is related to the `Victim` table.

Comment: Yes, but i need to move the values to start. that is my end goal

Comment: this is an example of what happens: i'll get input like this: {None} {None} {} i want to end up with None, None, ' ' i'll do further clean up once i can figure out how to separte each value between the brackets. i tried this code, but it only gets the first set between the brackets the result looks like this  source:{None} {None} {} Result {None} i've used this 
SELECT  arrestnumber, injurycategory,SUBSTRING(InjuryCategory, CHARINDEX(@ST, InjuryCategory),
(CHARINDEX(@EN, InjuryCategory)+LEN(@EN))-CHARINDEX(@ST, InjuryCategory))
from TblVictim
order by ArrestNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `STRING_SPLIT()`, `STUFF()` and `STRING_AGG()` to get the expected results. Note, that `STRING_SPLIT()` orders the results (using `enable_ordinal` parameter) only in Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics (serverless SQL pool only), so `STRING_AGG()` may aggregate differently.

Test data:

```
SELECT *
INTO tblVictim
FROM (
   VALUES ('{Abrasision} {None} {Bruise}')
) t (InjuryCategory)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(STUFF(s.[value], 1, CHARINDEX('{', s.[value]), ''), ' ') AS Category
FROM tblVictim t
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.InjuryCategory, '}') s
WHERE s.[value] <> ''
```

Result:

```
Category
----------------------
Abrasision None Bruise
```

Comment: This almost works, however, there are tons of values besides abrasion, none and bruise... I need to get all the values in the table for the column injurycategory in the table tblVictim

Comment: one last ask: for each value between {} it creates a new row, can i get it all on one row ? so on one row, it appreas as 'No Appraent Injurt' as one line, none,  then the null {No Apparent Injury} {None} {} No
{No Apparent Injury} {None} {} Apparent
{No Apparent Injury} {None} {} Injury
{No Apparent Injury} {None} {} None
{No Apparent Injury} {None} {}

Comment: ok. so, i'm trying to get the results like this: an arrest with victim injury gets reported in the injury category. the problem is, the feed has the values in between brackets, i would like the results to be on one line. this is almost working, except it's taking the values and put them on separate lines, i'd like to get this Abrasions, Brusies, Shot, all with the arrest# as the first column and all of the injuries in the next column in one row

Comment: @JuniorVasquez, I think you want to aggregate the results. The answer is updated.

Comment: is there a solution that puts all the results in one column ? i cna't seem to find it

Comment: @JuniorVasquez, it's really difficult without sample data and expected results. Probably `SELECT CONCAT(arrest#, STRING_AGG(...) FROM tblVictim ...` is what you want.

Comment: this is good, but when the field is too long, what can i do ? i get this error: Msg 9829, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
STRING_AGG aggregation result exceeded the limit of 8000 bytes. Use LOB types to avoid result truncation.

Comment: @JuniorVasquez, convert to `nvarchar(max)` or `varchar(max)` as is explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types).

Comment: FIgured out the error, this works to perfection. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of SQL Server, you can combine `STRING_SPLIT` and `TRIM`

```sql
SELECT TRIM('{}' FROM s.[value]) AS Category
FROM TblVictim v
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(v.InjuryCategory, ' ') s
WHERE s.[value] <> '';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efddaf348c47a921da5e1124410ce76c)

Comment: This is great, can we account for when something like this happens ? bruises};{Abrasions everything is great as seen below, except for when the ; is between the brackets ?  this is the result when that happens 
bruises};{Abrasions
parts
TROUBLE

Comment: Maybe `CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(v.InjuryCategory, ';', ' '), ' ') s` alternatively you can split on `}` and trim `' ;{'` instead. If you want me to answer all possible problems you will need to give a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty, since this is delimited data, pretend it's XML. Setup:

```
DECLARE @tblVictim TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, InjuryCategory NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @tblVictim(InjuryCategory) 
VALUES 
   ('{Abrasision} {None} {Bruise}'),
   ('{Abrasision} {<5} {Bruise; very severe}');
```

Query:

```
WITH data AS (
    SELECT ID, xml = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(InjuryCategory, 
        '{', '<i><![CDATA['), 
        '}', ']]></i>') AS XML
    )
    FROM @tblVictim
)
SELECT ID, node.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM data
CROSS APPLY xml.nodes('i') AS nodes(node)
```

Note that this completely breaks down (with no easy fixes) if there are unbalanced delimiters.

Comment: this does what i wanted, but i get an error: Msg 9423, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
XML parsing: line 1, character 300, incorrect CDATA section syntax

Comment: @JuniorVasquez: Exactly per my comments: this completely stops working if you have data in there that contains unbalanced `{` `}` pairs, which is the most likely explanation for the error (you get this if there's a `{` with no matching `}`; for example, because the string got cut off). This is why (ideally) you don't do processing like this in T-SQL, but in client applications.